# Postdoc health insurance for dependents in US?

Tags: postdocs, health

I am looking towards a postdoc position at a US institution. Do university employers typically contribute to/pay for health insurance coverage for dependents of the employed (i.e. my wife and child)? As a PhD student, my health insurance was covered, but we had to pay $2000 up front each year for my wife's health insurance...

Comment: This is best asked directly to the HR folks at a particular university.

Comment: Whether health insurance is offered to postdocs and their dependents and how much it will cost if it is offered can vary dramatically from one institution to another.

Comment: @BrianBorchers: Can you give some examples of institutions where it is *not* offered?

Comment: @NateEldredge I think it's more a question of what the contributions are, particularly for dependent coverage. $2000/year additional for adding spouse+dependent coverage is higher than at my institution but sounds fairly reasonable.

Comment: To clarify: do you want to know about what coverage is typically offered? Or do you want to know if the coverage is typically paid for (in whole or in part)? Your language is "provide...options" which is unclear to me.

Comment: @Dawn, I'm wanting to know if it is typically paid for (in whole or in part). Sorry for the abiguity.

Comment: I realize this will vary and I don't have a particular institution to talk to yet, just trying to get a general idea for what most people have encountered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, US universities generally offer health insurance to spouses and children of full-time employees, especially academic employees.  You'll likely have to pay for it (part or all of the policy's cost), but normally the premiums would be deducted from each paycheck, not paid in advance.

Most universities have public websites for their human resources office, where you can read about employee benefits.